# Probability question: what's the sample space?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was solving this question, and while I can obtain the correct answer, I'm unsure what the sample space is.

A medical test is positive in 99% of the cases where a person in a certain population has a certain disease. But it also gives a false 'positive' result in 1% of the cases where the person is actually healthy. What is the probability that a person is sick if the test is positive, given that 0.5% of the population has the disease.

I think the sample space is the following:

Let P be the population in the question and for $p \in P$, we write $H_p$ if the person is healthy and $S_p$ if the person is sick.

Then the sample space $\Omega$ is $$\bigcup_{p \in P} \{H_p,S_p\}$$

Is this correct? Is it a good thing tl keep in mind sample spaces when approaching problems, because here it seems rather useless.

Comment: "Is it a good thing tl keep in mind sample spaces when approaching problems, because here it seems rather useless" It is **always** useless (and I might have explained in details why, a few times on the site).

Comment: That seems a rather exaggerated answer. You must know in what space the events are living.

Comment: If you *were* to insist on describing a sample space, then it should also include information as to whether or not they *tested* positive in addition to whether or not they are *actually* sick.  I would have described the sample space as $\{(p,H_p, T_p)~:~p\in P\}$ where $H_p$ and $T_p$ are $1$ or $0$ corresponding to whether or not the specific person in question is healthy or not and whether or not the specific person in question tested positive or not respectively.

Comment: You will not be able to answer the question without knowing the general prevalence of the disease

Comment: Yes I will. The solution is 99/298

Comment: "You must know in what space the events are living" What for? Please be specific.

Comment: "*Yes I will*."  Then you are missing information in your post.  This is a direct application of Baye's Theorem.  You have been given $P(T\mid H^c), P(T^c\mid H^c), P(T\mid H)$ and $P(T^c\mid H)$ where $T$ represents the test came back positive and $H$ that the person is healthy.  You are asked to calculate $P(H^c\mid T)$.  This was the entirety of the information you gave us in your post.  The problem is intended to be a routine application of [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem), but to continue you *must* have more information than what you have given.

Comment: Let B be the event that the test is positive, Z that the person is sick. G that the person is health. Then $P(Z|B) = \frac{P(Z)P(B|Z)}{P(B|Z)P(Z) + P(B|G)P(G)}$ and all these things are given

Comment: Where was $P(Z)$ given? Where was $P(G)$ given?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to include this information. You were totally right. Solving it was not the intent of the question though. Will edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has already shown that s/he knows how to solve the Bayes' Theorem question in the comments.  Here I'll discuss only the question of how to represent the sample space.

In my experience, most often if we want our sample space to be equiprobable to facilitate probability calculations by using counting methods, we will think of the sample space as the population of people about which our data is collected and from which we will be asking probability questions about.  I'll refer to the set of people as $\Omega$.  In doing so, we will need to have a function or functions which give information about the person(s) selected.

For example, let $Info$ be a function $\Omega\to \{0,1\}^2$ where $Info(p)=\begin{cases}(0,0)&\text{if the person is healthy and tested negative}\\(1,0)&\text{if the person is sick and tested negative}\\(0,1)&\text{if the person is healthy and tested positive}\\(1,1)&\text{if the person is sick and tested positive}\end{cases}$

This is the only information relevant to the Bayes' theorem question, and so all of it must be included in how we define $Info$, but we could have had more information able to be conveyed by $Info$ if we so wished or if we wanted to later change the problem... for example by including age as a factor, or gender, mother's maiden name, favorite color, or even what brand perfume they use.  The possibilities are endless, and are mostly irrelevant.

If you wish not to define a function (*or acknowledge the existence of such a function*) outside of the sample space, you could simply include the information within the sample space itself, letting our sample space be instead $$\left\{(p,S_p,T_p)~:~p\in\Omega\right\}$$ where $$~S_p=\begin{cases}0&\text{if the person is healthy}\\1&\text{if the person is sick}\end{cases},~T_p\begin{cases}0&\text{if the person tested negative}\\1&\text{if the person tested positive}\end{cases}$$

We could also have defined our sample space to be something else entirely where we don't care about it being equiprobable, in which case we could have simply taken our sample space as being $\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$, or heck... even worse as simply $\{0,1\}$.  These samplespaces are less than useful though as they are either not equiprobable or don't convey enough information to describe each event.

---

In your attempt at defining a sample space, not only is the notation horribly awkward, you have not included any reference to whether or not the person tested positive or negative for the illness.

---

As mentioned elsewhere in comments as well, actually taking the time to define the sample space adequately for every problem is generally a waste of time.  We know that we *can* define it if we wanted to, but the action of doing so plays little or no role in actually arriving at an answer to the question we were originally being asked.

Comment: When you define the sample space, don't you mean $p \in P$ instead of $p \in \Omega$?

Comment: With the way I wrote it, no I meant $p\in\Omega$ since I stated in my first paragraph that I refer to the set of people as $\Omega$.  I was trying to avoid using the same letter for multiple purposes, and trying to be consistent with what symbol I use to notate something throughout the post.  You can of course change what symbol you use for whatever at your leisure.  "*A rose by any other name*" and whatnot...

Comment: Ah okay I see. I was just confused because I usually preserve the omega letter for sample space. Thanks for your answer. It clears up a lot.